# Finding the inverse $(D - bb^T)^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Finding the inverse $(D - bb^T)^{-1}$

Where $D$ is a diagional matrix with all positive entries, and $bb^T$ is the symmetric matrix generated by the vector $b$. I know that $\det(bb^T) = 0$, and I workouted the $2\times2$ case, but I could not generalize the result to $n\times n$.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

Use the [Sherman Morrison Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula).